# Relationship between gauss elimination and vertex deficiency in associated graph

Tags: graph-theory, gaussian-elimination

Currently reading through this document : https://www.jstor.org/stable/2100866

First few definitions (extracted from the paper)

> Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ for each $v \in V$ we define
> $$
> A(v) = \left\{ w \in V : (v,w) \in E \right\} \\
> B(v) = \left\{ u \in V : (u,v) \in E \right\}
> $$

> Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ for each $v \in V$ we define
> $$
> D(v) = \left\{ (x,y) : x \to v, v \to y, y \notin A(x), x \neq y  \right\}
> $$

Later the following is stated:

> The notion of vertex elimination arises in the solution fo sparse system of linear equations by Gaussian Elimination. Given any $n \times n$ matrix $M = (m_{ij})$ which represents the coefficients of a set of linear equations, we can construct an ordered graph $G_{\alpha} = (V,E,\alpha)$, where vertex $v_i$ corresponds to row $i$, and $(v_i,v_j) \in E$ iff $m_{ij} \neq 0$ and $i \neq j$. The unordered graph $G = (V,E)$ corresponds to the equivalence class of matrices $PMP^T$, where $P$ is any permutation matrix. If we solve the system with coefficients $M$ using Gaussian Elimination, eliminating the variables in the order $1,2,\ldots, n$ then the edges of $D_{i-1}(v_i)$ correspond exactly to the new non zero-elements created when row $i$ is eliminated.

To test this I tried one step of reduction for the following matrix

$$
M = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And a step of elimination (subtracting to the 2nd row twice the first one) yields

$$
M = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Now on the original matrix calculating $D(2)$ should give me edges corresponding to the **new** non-zero entries. However I don't understand how this map with the step of elimination I did.

I think I am miss-understanding the meaning of *eliminated row*.

Can anyone clarify the meaning with the given example of matrix $M$?

Comment: I think the system is eliminating rows rather than columns in the gaussian elimination. So your first step will be to nullify the first row (except for the 2), and you will add new zeros in the third and fifth columns, as indicated by the edges of your graph.

Comment: I think I figured. But I'd like to know how to draw graphs using tikz on mathexchange before posting an answer.

Comment: I don't think you can use tikz directly on mathexchange

Comment: ok, I'll find another way soon (probably just attaching the picture generated).